# check for any content in php

Tags: php, post

I want to see if there are any POST vars set. Is there anyway i can do this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
if (!empty($_POST)) {
    // handle post data
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
if(count($_POST) > 0) {
    // Post vars are set
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple, $_POST is an array containing all POST vars, just count how any items are in the array and you know if there are any set.

```
echo count($_POST);
```